# Will it be OK to access data through a data segment register after I disturb gdt table?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, memory-segmentation, gdt

I had set the gdt table using this data

```
uint16_t gdt_table[][4] = {
    {   0,         0,      0,      0       },
    {   0xFFFF,    0x0000, 0x9a00, 0x00cf  },
    {   0xFFFF,    0x0000, 0x9200, 0x00cf  },
};
```

And I do `mov $16, %eax` ; `mov %eax, %ds` to load DS with a GDT entry.

Now I change the gdt_table, or just set it to zero (to disturb it) but don't reload `%ds` again.

---

These are my questions

- I want to konw is it still ok for me to access data through `%ds`(after I disturb the gdt table)
- Will cpu check gdt table every time I access data through `%ds`?(So when will cpu check gdt table, only when mov? Or every time I access data through data segment register?)

I think cpu should check gdt table only when `mov` happened, and then load some information somewhere, as it can be more effective(by checking less often), is it right?

Comment: Generally the descriptor tables (GDT/LDT) should only be accessed when loading a segreg with `mov` or `pop` (or eg by `iret`, `retf`, `call`, `jmp`), yes.

Comment: *And then I do `mov $16, %ds`* - That won't assemble, there is no mov-immediate to Sreg.  You'd have to mov-immediate to a general-purpose register (or memory) and then mov from there into DS.

Comment: You're correct, the segment base/limit are only updated when you load a new value in the the Sreg.  They can't reload from the GDT in memory on their own.

Comment: It's definitely not the case that the GDT is accessed every time a segment register is used. Segment registers have a "hidden" portion where the GDT data is cached. That said, I don't recommend changing the GDT (at all) but if you do, reload the segment registers before they reload unexpectedly.

Comment: Of note: this technique of changing the GDT but not reloading segment registers is very similar to *unreal mode* where the `loadall` instruction was used to set the segment shadow registers for `ds` to plain 32 bit addressing without switching to protected mode.  This works as long as nothing reloads `ds`.

Comment: @fuz: Note that loading DS in real mode only updates the base, it doesn't reset the limit to 64K, so if anything later changes DS, you can change it back easily while still in real mode without using loadall.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode (And stuff that saves/restores DS will Just Work if you left it with a value of zero to match the segment base.)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to konw is it still ok for me to access data through %ds(after I disturb the gdt table)

It's safe; unless something reloads %ds from the GDT later. It isn't necessarily uncommon for interrupt handlers to save "interrupted code's DS" and then load it again before returning to the interrupted code.

> Will cpu check gdt table every time I access data through %ds?

For performance (to avoid repeatedly accessing GDT and doing protection checks) the CPU caches the (segment base, limit, attributes) information in "hidden" parts of the segment register. This information is also saved and reloaded during transitions to/from SMM and transitions between guest and hypervisor; so GDT isn't used for those cases either.

The only cases where CPU will access GDT for DS is if there's an explicit load of DS (a `mov`, `lds` or `pop ds`), or a hardware task switch (e.g. from using a task gate). For "interrupt handler returning to virtual8086 mode" (where CPU does restore values from DS) the GDT isn't used because CPU is loading real mode compatible values. For CS and SS (but not DS) CPU will also use GDT when using interrupt/trap gates or call gates and returning (via. `iret` or `retf`).